# firebase - setting specific fields as private

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to set up certain fields to be private on my user profiles. I have a user documents with name, email, etc but I want to make the gold field read only as I plan to use a cloud function to update this value when a user makes an in app purchase. I've not done in app purchases before so this is the only way I can think of doing it.

I understand I can use wildcard vars in the path when using Firestore security rules, however as far as I'm aware, I can only use wildcard vars in place of the documents and collections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that wildards can only be used to identify collections and documents, but not fields. However one option you could have is to create an additional 'private collection' which you could secure with the standard security rules. For example -

- users

  - user1

    - email
    - name
- gold

  - user1

    - goldValue

Then in your security could look something like -

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /gold/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /users/{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, This looks like the solution I would need to implement